# Сессии пользователя на php

Tags: php, авторизация

Пишу аторизацию пользователя через вк.

Получаю данные, если пользователь есть - обновляем, если нет, создаем.

Записываем все это в сессию пользователя.

Дальше нужно немного разъяснений из первых уст.

Как я понимаю (исправляйте, если что), сессия хранится пока пользователь не закроет браузер или 24 минуты при отсутсвии активности. Поэтому в куки планирую записать ай-ди пользователя в зашифрованном виде (расшифровка на сервере). Дальше если человек заходит с куками - берем его данные из базы и создаем с ними сессию.

Как это сделать я понимаю, но почитал инфу и все пишут, что нужно хранить идентификатор сессии? Что это значит, ведь сессия уничтожается или нет? Как правильно реализовать повторный вход, чтобы не делать ошибок?

Comment: Срок жизни сессии величина настраиваемая

Comment: Если мне нужно, чтобы человек заходил и через неделю тоже был аторизован, получается, что нужно выставить срок жизни сессий 2 недели (к примеру) и срок жизни куки тоже 2 недели. Правильно авторизовавать именно через сессии или не обязательно?

Comment: Почему нельзя просто хранить ай-ди в куках?

Comment: Если кука сессии себя скомпрометирует - пользователь может перелогиниться и получить новую. Как вы инвалидируете свой айдишник?

Comment: Спасибо, понял логику. А про срок хранения - я верно понял? (выше написал)

Comment: Верно. Нужно выставить 3 переменные `session.` в конфиге: `gc_maxlifetime`, `cache_expire` и `cookie_lifetime`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54838/discussion-between---and-vp-arth).

Comment: @vp_arth что Вы имели ввиду под этим: `Если кука сессии себя скомпрометирует - пользователь может перелогиниться и получить новую. Как вы инвалидируете свой айдишник?` ?

Comment: @wcobalt, короче говоря, если некто сворует куку - её можно сменить.